# Android No definition - Resource.raw

Tags: android, resources

Xamarin - Andriod
I tried to play a "test.mp3" in a `raw` folder in resources, but there's always this exception:

```
_play = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.test);
```

> there's no definition for 'raw'

I've searched a lot on the web but didn't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

public static MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid);

_mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.songname);

Try this and Let me know :)